# Shapefile created in R not showing in ArcGIS

Tags: r, arcgis

I used R to create shapefiles to make a home range. When trying to open the Shapefiles in ArcGIS, the files will open fine if when just loading them but if i then open a shapefile from a different source it will not appear on the map. A similar thing occurs if I open my original shapefile first; the files created on R will not show. It appears that they are incompatible with each other?

I'm not sure if this is a code issue in R or not but I have included the code I used to export the Shapefile in case it is. Thanks in advance for any help.

writeOGR(e.all.50.kde,dsn = ".",layer = "elephantKDE50",driver = "ESRI Shapefile")

Comment: Not sure if this is super helpful but maybe try exporting the shapefile as a different type of geo-file - like geojson?

Comment: I'm not sure how to create a geojson, search it and this was the code I found but it doesn't seem to be working? Here's the code and the error                                                  writeOGR(e.all.95.kde, dsn="path/test_geojson.GeoJSON", layer="elephant95", driver="GeoJSON")
Error in writeOGR(e.all.95.kde, dsn = "path/test_geojson.GeoJSON", layer = "elephant95",  : 
  Creation of output file failed

Comment: I've worked it out I think, both shapefiles are shown but for some reason on has not been plotted in the correct position so does not show up